# How do I correct this misplaced modifier?

Tags: grammar

How do I correct the misplaced modifier "to see how hard they were" in the following question?

> Do college admission officers compare your transcript grades to other students in your school who took the same classes to see how hard they were?

I think most people would understand this question as it was intended, but,  grammatically speaking, "to see how hard they were" modifies "other students in your school," so it's not a 100% correct sentence.

Comment: This question cannot be answered until you explain *why* you think there is a misplaced modifier. You need to be explicit about what you think the sentence is trying to express, and what you think it would commonly be interpreted as expressing instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part "to see how hard they were" in your sentence is technically modifying the closest thing, which is "other students in your school who took the same classes". Most people would not have a problem understanding what you mean. It's the officers who are comparing grades to see how hard the classes/subjects were.

Here are a few minor changes, before getting to solving that problem.

This is the base form.

> (1) Do college admission officers compare your grades with **the grades of** other students in your school who took the same classes to see how hard **the classes** were?

I dropped "transcript" because it is not really needed here. Now, you can replace "grades of" with "those of".

> (2) Do college admission officers compare your grades with **those of** other students in your school who took the same classes to see how hard **the classes** were?

If you want, you can drop "students" too.

> ... compare your grades with **those of others** in your school ...

You can change "in your school" to "in your class". A class is *"a group of students who are taught together at school, college, or university"* (Collins).

> (3) Do college admission officers compare your grades with those of others in your class  to see how hard **the classes** were?

You can use "deduce" or "determine" instead of "see" if you want to get fancy.

> ... to deduce how hard **the classes** were?

I wonder how an officer will have the grades of other students from your class if they don't apply to that particular college. However, your transcript will show your grades and the class averages for the subjects you took. A different way to say this would be

> (4) Do college admission officers compare your grades with the class averages to determine the level of difficulty of the classes and how well you performed among your peers?

I believe both (3) and (4) solves the problem of the misplaced modifier. I am sure there are other ways that I can't think of right now.